# Magic Trackpad stuck battery

Tags: hardware, battery, trackpad, repair, magic-trackpad

I have a Magic Trackpad that sat unused in a work drawer for a few months. Like a total noob, I neglected to remove the batteries.

I recently reconfigured my workspace and decided to start using trackpad once more, but to my horror, the batteries had corroded and the one furthest in, is very very stuck.

I have tried a long neck, thin screwdriver to try and pry away some of the corrosion around the edge, and lot of banging/ knocking/ cursing, but the battery is still in place.

I welcome any suggestions on how I can remove the other battery and hopefully resurrect this trackpad into working order. I open to suggested chemicals/ power tools etc.

Many thanks in advance community!

Comment: I'd just finished cooking some salmon when I saw the response from @Buscar, so I had a cut lemon "in-flight". A little fresh squeeze and a half dozen qTips later, I have a functioning trackpad! Thanks community!! Thanks Buscar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the gel containing battery acid has leaked out and dried up.

You need to make it muddy again to be able to remove it, since dry removal is not possible.

There are multiple methods to do that described [here](http://cleaning.lovetoknow.com/How_to_Clean_Leaking_AA_Batteries). (Vinegar, Lemon juice, and others).

Example:

Mix water and baking soda into a thick paste. Start with about a teaspoon of baking soda and add water a few drops at a time until it can be mixed into a thick paste.

Apply the baking soda paste generously to any corroded areas using cotton swabs. Allow the paste to sit for 15 minutes.

Use a slightly moistened toothbrush to gently agitate the paste. Rinse the toothbrush often, and continue until the majority of the paste has been scrubbed away. In hard to reach spaces use q-tip to deliver the paste.

Needless to say, use gloves!

Comment: In my experience, the stuff that leaks out of modern disposable batteries ("alkaline batteries") is a base, not an acid, and the right way to hydrate / neutralize it is vinegar. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the vinegar method for a while but with no success, using force just resulted in a bent sufface. Another theory I had is heating it so it would expand, but just ruined the plastic.

So I ended up drilling it out. I had to use a series of bits since the notch prevented a good grip and the material is **very** tough.

[image: drilled out]

I used a paperclip to make the connection.

[image: paperclip]

Hardly noticeable :)

[image: not dead]

Comment: Drilling it out did the trick for me, thanks! Took some time to get into it but i was able to pull the battery out with the bit itself.
In my case the dried up residue was already removed, the notch cap came off when i first tried to loosen it with a screwdriver. What actually held the battery in was the outer plastic of the battery that stuck to the sides which ripped off eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I used a self-tapping screw (for sheet metal) to drill into the bottom of the stuck battery. Then I turned a long screw into the hole and pulled out the battery.
One advantage of this method is there is no banging or impact to the trackpad.

Others above have great methods for cleaning the compartment. The trackpad is good as new.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a similar problem. I have managed to extract the stuck batteries after flushing of the battery compartment with half a teaspoon of vinegar and tapping the trackpad.